# When we start android studio to create new project then why it auto created MainActivity

Tags: java, android

Why does the Android Studio launch to create a new project, so why does it become the first activity in the name of MainActivity?

Comment: Are you asking why it creates one?  To help you out in case you didn't know how to start.  You can also tell it not to.

Comment: You have a choice to add no activity to the new project.

Comment: that is you who told it to create an activity.

Comment: Welcome to SO @AfrozAhmad . ..Please refer this [How to ask well question on stackoverflow](https://www.quora.com/What-are-your-best-tips-to-ask-questions-on-Stack-Overflow)

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to add no activity, it will not create any activity

[image]

If you choose Empty Activity then in next window you can change name from `MainActivity` to something else you want

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just before the choosing activity window there's a window in which you can change the name of main activity.Furthermore in manifest.xml if you change the parent activity to whatever activity you want that then activity you have made parent in manifest that will invoke when you open the app.

Answer (score 0):

Because in Android, each and every app must have a single activity. That's way Android Studio create itself a MainActivity.